# Some static images fail to render on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a simple app that shows a list of content that I can tap into and view more detail about that content. I'm experiencing a strange issue where **in Release mode** on a SM Galaxy S7, the static images I attempt to load are not always rendering. Note: This ONLY happens on a physical device, release mode in the emulator works as expected. Additionally, whenever the static images fail to render, I can exit the app (like, going to multitasking and back) and the static images will appear correctly for the remainder of that session.

It feels like a memory issue, but I have no clue. I've tried directly setting a `width` and `height` prop on the  and i've also tried putting the static images directly in the Android project instead of bundling with the js.

I'm loading the images just as simply as the following: 
`<Image source={require('app/images/shipping.png')} />`

Another important note: When this issue occurs, it also happens for the default navigation back button provided by the react-navigation library, so I assume it's not some kind of way I'm loading the images.

**Specs:**
"react": "16.2.0"
"react-native": "0.53"

Comment: How do you load the images? Where do you load them from? Including some code might help.

Comment: Hey! I just updated the post with that and added another note below it.